# Add a multiple criteria search engine on a Wordpress Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to build a real estate ad list using Wordpress custom post types. I know how to create custom fields and how to get an array of posts that matches some custom fields values using WP_Query() and 'meta_query'.

I want to know how can I build a paginated list of posts filtered by a search form.

For example : the user selects its criterias (the number of rooms etc.) he clics on the search button and the posts that matches his criterias are displayed. If there are more than 10 result, he can click on "next page".

I was not able to find a way to do that properly.

Thank you.

Comment: You need form with your terms for the filter. Then on submit get selected terms and run a query to filter your posts with them.

Comment: I have already managed to do that. The problem is that this technique does not use the loop so you cannot pût a pagination like wp navi.

Answer (score 0):

You can paginate by using `paged` and passing queried page.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged
) );
```

From there use `paginate_links()` to build your pagination.

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
        'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'prev_next'    => true,
        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s', __( 'Prev Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
        'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s', __( 'Next Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
    ) );
endif;
```

If you dont want to see the numbers just hide them with css

Comment: Thank you ! This is what I wanted to do, but :

    my form uses the get method so there are get parameters in the URL. When I go to another page, parameters are duplicated like : ?city=paris&nb_pieces=3#038;nb_pieces=3. When I remove

    'base' => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),

it works and parameters are not duplicated. Is this parameter mandatory ? (I was not able to understand what it is for).

Comment: When I go to another page than the first one, the results of my query is displayed but wordpress displays the 404 page. I work on the post archive page on the 2021 default wordpress theme (for test purposes...) and I left all the default code so I can see the error text.Even if I achieve to remove these text error, the http code sent througth the headers will be 404 so it is not a good idea to remove the errors. Do you have any idea?

Comment: So if I understand, I have to put all my code in the archive-[CPT_NAME].php without the default loop so Wordpress won't display the posts the default way. I have to create my own loop (using foreach) to display posts. Am I right?

Thank you!